# Handle multiple child database with root database

Tags: database

My system have 6 Database: 1 primary, 5 secondary. Each child database contain table "User" with the same structure. Primary Database contain infomation connect to child DB. I want get data from 5 child DB to statistic. 
I think there are 2 ways:
- Get data from 5 child DB, handle by code. then show to my screen.
- On Primary Database, create table "User" same structure child DB. Secondary DBs only send data contain "status" as created or updated. On Primary DB, I'll update or create on "User" table. After, I'll get data from "User" table on primary DB to show my screen.

Currently, I use Mysql InnoDB vs PHP. Can you help me choose the best way?
What database is the most relevant in this case? Mysql, MongoDB, PostgreSql,...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the View in primary database to get data from 5 child DB.